# Can not access to solr cloud tree view, replica deletion keeps getting timeout

Tags: solr, timeout, replication, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I have a Solr Cloud 6.6.5 cluster with more than 200 shards. I'm trying to use the Collections API to move/delete replicas because I'm having space issues on some of the machines, but I get a "deletereplica timed out" warning and it does nothing. Also, when I try to access the Cloud > Tree view, the instance disconnects. I tried it on multiple instances, I think any machine with ZooKeeper is enough to give this error. I am running a different ZooKeeper cluster facing a different Solr cluster on a different port, no problem there.

I tried increasing the amount of ram in the shards, restarted ZooKeeper, restarted all the machines I was having problems with. Sometimes it just corrects itself just by restarting but not this time.